# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to unobfuscate unsigned char array and convert it to NSString

Tags: objective-c, c, memory, malloc

I have a simple class that uses SHA-512 to obfuscate/unobfuscate strings. Obfuscated strings are stored as arrays of unsigned chars and are unobfuscated at runtime by XORing against an SHA hash of some key string. Here's how this class looks like:

```
#import "Obfuscator.h"
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

static unsigned char firstKey[] = {0x7, 0x86, 0xF6, 0xAB, 0xFD, 0xC1, 0x86, 0xAD, 0x9B, 0x9E, 0xAA, 0xE9, 0x10, 0x54, 0x2D, 0x74, 0x11, 0x63, 0x7, 0xE8};

static unsigned char secondKey[] = {0x1E, 0x9A, 0xB4, 0xED, 0x9D, 0xE6, 0x91, 0xA7, 0x87, 0x9C, 0x91, 0xB3, 0x40};

static unsigned char thirdKey[] = {0xB, 0x91, 0xF7, 0xED, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0x91, 0x9A, 0xDA, 0x88, 0xAA, 0x94, 0x4B, 0x12, 0xB, 0x74};

@implementation Obfuscator

- (void)test
{
    NSString *just = [self stringFromEncryptedKey:firstKey ofLength:sizeof(firstKey)];
    NSString *try = [self stringFromEncryptedKey:secondKey ofLength:sizeof(secondKey)];
    NSString *this = [self stringFromEncryptedKey:thirdKey ofLength:sizeof(thirdKey)];
}

- (NSString *)stringFromEncryptedKey:(unsigned char *)key ofLength:(int)length
{
    unsigned char *obfuscator = malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));

    NSData *encryptionData = [@"MyTopSecretEncryptionKey"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CC_SHA512(encryptionData.bytes, (CC_LONG)encryptionData.length, obfuscator);

    unsigned char *unobfuscated = malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char)); ;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        unobfuscated[i] = key[i] ^ obfuscator[i];
    }

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:unobfuscated length:length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", result);

    free(obfuscator);
    free(unobfuscated);

    return result;
}

@end
```

When I run this code and call test method I get all kinds of memory errors. Without malloc guard I get an "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed" error at some point, usually when the first key is unobfuscated and logged to console. If malloc guard is enabled then execution stops with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when SHA-512 hash is calculated. I'm not sure how to debug this kind of stuff. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1: SHA512 output length:
incorrect: `unsigned char *obfuscator = malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));`
correct:   `unsigned char *obfuscator = malloc(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH);`

Error 2: Arbitrary data is not necessarily an `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, Base64 is a better option.

Error 3: `result` is created with `unobfuscated`, probably should be `obfuscated`.

Example code:

```
- (NSString *)stringFromEncryptedKey:(unsigned char *)key ofLength:(int)length {
    NSMutableData *unobfuscatedData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:key length:length * sizeof(unsigned char)];
    NSMutableData *obfuscatedData   = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length * sizeof(unsigned char)];
    unsigned char *unobfuscated     = unobfuscatedData.mutableBytes;
    unsigned char *obfuscated       = obfuscatedData.mutableBytes;

    NSMutableData *obfuscatorData   = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char *obfuscator       = obfuscatorData.mutableBytes;

    NSData *encryptionData = [@"MyTopSecretEncryptionKey" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CC_SHA512(encryptionData.bytes, (CC_LONG)encryptionData.length, obfuscator);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        obfuscated[i] = obfuscator[i] ^ unobfuscated[i];
    }

    NSString *result = [obfuscatedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    NSLog(@"result:       %@", result);

    return result;
}
```

Output:

> result: TXkxMjNTZWNyZXQ0NTZTdHJpbmc=
>   result: VGVzdFN0cmluZ09uZQ==
>   result: QW4wdGgzclQzc3RJbnB1dA==

Comment: Damn it, I forgot about sha digest length. Thank you, it solved the problem.